# How to make a batch file loop through sub-directories

Tags: batch-file

Some context:
I start off with around 100 jpg images named in the format of AFSM-DDMMYY_doe-john.jpg which are then sorted into folders based on their names only with the following script:

foldercreator.bat

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.jpg') do (
    set "filename1=%%~i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "folder1=!filename1:~12,-4!"
    mkdir "!folder1!" 2>nul
    move "!filename1!" "!folder1!" >nul
)
```

I then remove the _last-first part of the filename so the images end up in the format of AFSM-DDMMYY.jpg This is done using the script below:

nameremover.bat

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a *.jpg') do (
    set "filename1=%%~i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "name1=!filename1:~0,11!"
    ren "!filename1!" "!name1!.jpg"
)
```

The resulting folders end up being named doe-john with AFSM-DDMMYY.jpg images in them. These folders are all within a common folder for this purpose. This works great but I would like to be able to run nameremover.bat from within the common folder so that it runs itself throughout all of the doe-john folders instead of me having to move it to each folder and then run it in there individually. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you split the file names by character positions rather than by the `_` character? Could there occur more than one `_` in the names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is to create a directory to contain your batch files - common names are `batch` or `belfry` and include that directoryname in your `path` variable. That way, any batch files in the directory may be executed regardless of your current directory.

Oh - btw : why don't you just use

```
move "!filename1!" "!folder1!\!filename1:~0,11!!filename1:~-4!" >nul
```

in your first batch?

---

When you specify a path to an executable (eg `c:\some\directory\executable.exe`) then that will be the file that will be executed. If however you omit the directory and simply execute `executable.exe` then an attempt is made to locate the file in the current directory. If this fails, then the environment variable `path` is examined and the first matching executable found on the `path` will be run.

Hence, if you modify your `path` to include a directory such as `c:\batch` then any attempt to run an executable will run it if `executablename.exe` is present in the `c:\batch` directory.

Executable files come in many flavours, the most important of which are `.bat`, `.cmd` and `.exe` and may be invoked by using their *base*name, so executing `fred` will locate `fred.bat`, `fred.cmd`, `fred.exe` in each of `.` (the current directory) and `%path%` (an environment variable containing a semicolon-separated list of directorynames)

You *can* alter *path* using windows, but a 3rd-party utility like `path editor` (Google it) makes it easy.

So - all you need do is establish a directory to contain your batchfiles (you're already doing this in your posted batch with the `mkdir` command (although it's more common to use `md` which is a synonym of `mkdir`)) Then move your batches to that directory, and you can run the batch using its basename, regardless of where your current directory happens to be.

Actually, I store more than batches there - I use it for all my utility `.exe`s as well - like `sed` for instance.

Analysing your code,

> @echo off &setlocal

The `&` cascades the two commands. `@echo off` turns command-echoing `off` and `setlocal` establishes a local environment which ensures that any changes to the environment (variables created or deleted, etc.) are restored to their original condition at the end of the batch. Note this doesn't restore added/deleted/changed/moved files - just the environment variables.

> for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.jpg') do (

Perform a `dir` command to find all the `.jpg` files; name only and no directory names. Put this list into memory as if it was a file. "Read" the list, line by line and assign each line's content to `%%i` in turn.

> set "filename1=%%~i"

set the environment variable `filename1` to the content of `%%i`=the content of the `dir` line.

> setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

NEST a new local environment, but this one has `delayedexpansion` invoked so that `!var!` means "the current value of `var` whereas `%var%` means "the value of `var` **as it was when the** `for`** was encountered**

> set "folder1=!filename1:~12,-4!"

set `folder1` to the *current* value of `filename1`, from the 13th character (counting starts from "character 0") to the 4th character from the end.

> mkdir "!folder1!" 2>nul

make that directory, suppressing and error messages (like 'it already exists')

> move "!filename1!" "!folder1!" >nul

move the file to the new directory. Since `"folder1!" is a directory, the file will be moved into that directory. If it didn't exist, the`move`would move the file to a **file** named`"!folder1!"`

> )

...and end of the `code block` started by the `(` after the `do` a few lines ago.

**Caution**

`setlocal` establishes a *nested* local environment. These are limited. You should place an `endlocal` command after the `move` command to end the local environment, so your code should be creating and deleting a local environment for each file processed.

So, with the `move` replaced by the `move` I advocate, the change would mean that the destination for the move is [ the target directory in `folder1` \ the first 12 characters of `filename1` + the last 4 characters from `filename1` ]

which would obviate the `nameremover` process.

IOW,

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.jpg') do (
    set "filename1=%%~i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "folder1=!filename1:~12,-4!"
    mkdir "!folder1!" 2>nul
    move "!filename1!" "!folder1!\!filename1:~0,11!!filename1:~-4!" >nul
    ENDLOCAL
)
```

should do your processing without the need to do the 'nameremover' step. Put this in your `\batch` directory after making the `path` change, and you should be able to run the code directly from the prompt wherever you are on your system, including if you are logged into a different drive.

---

To establish a menu, the conventional approach is:

```
:again
cls
echo 1. do thing 1
echo 2. do thing 2
echo 3. do thing 3
echo q  quit
choice /c 123q /m please choose...
if errorlevel 4 goto :eof
if errorlevel 3 call batch3&goto again
if errorlevel 2 call batch2&goto again
if errorlevel 1 call batch1&goto again
goto again
```

`choice /?` at the prompt will yield a guide on how `choice` works.

`errorlevel` is set according to the character-position within the 
`/c` string of the key activated.

Since `if errorlevel n` is true if `errorlevel` is n **or greater than n**
the code must be constructed in reverse-value order.

The code to be executed will probably alter the value of `errorlevel`.
consequently, a `goto` is required after having executed the subsidiary
batch to ensure that the return from `batch3`, say isn't interpreted by
the remaining `if errorlevel` statements.

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply. The reason I didn't use that instead is because I've never used batch files before but this particular project requires it so I'm really just going off of what little I can find on the internet and making it fit my needs. Could you explain more how I would implement a directory and what the difference between my first batch file and your suggested change would be? Thank you.

Comment: Just got home and was able to try it out. Works perfectly and I appreciate you taking the time to explain to me how you did what you did as well so I understand it much better now. Much appreciated.

Comment: So you seem very knowledgeable in the ways of batch files so I was wondering if you could further help me. The script you gave me runs amazingly and I really appreciate that. One thing I am running into is that I have a lot of different types of files names that I generate often. I have edited the batch file you made for each of these situations and now have a bunch of the batch files. I was wondering if it was possible to make it so that when I run the script, it opens the cmd window and asks me which version to run from within the same batch file.